# Compare two tables and return list of mismatches

Tags: r

I'd like to be able to compare two tables and have R return a list of records and variables that don't match.

For example, with the following two tables

```
> df1
  id let num
1 1a   a   1
2 2b   b   2
3 3c   c   3
4 4d   d   4
5 5e   e   5
> df2
  id let num
1 1a   a   1
2 2b   b   2
3 3c   c   3
4 4d   e   4
5 5e   d   5
```

I would want a compare() function to return something like "id=4d, let" to let me know that the let variable in the record with id = 4d doesn't match.

I have seen the compare library in CRAN but it only returns TRUE or FALSE for the entire variable if there is a mismatch.  Is there a library with a different compare function, or a way to do this manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df1 <- read.table(text="
id let1 num1
1a   a   1
2b   b   2
3c   c   3
4d   d   4
5e   e   5", head=T, as.is=T)

df2 <- read.table(text="
id let2 num2
1a   a   1
2b   b   2
3c   c   3
4d   e   4
5e   d   5", head=T, as.is=T)

df <- merge(df1, df2, by="id")
df$let <- ifelse(df$let1 == df$let2, "equal", "not equal")
df$num <- ifelse(df$num1 == df$num2, "equal", "not equal")
df
#   id let1 num1 let2 num2       let   num
# 1 1a    a    1    a    1     equal equal
# 2 2b    b    2    b    2     equal equal
# 3 3c    c    3    c    3     equal equal
# 4 4d    d    4    e    4 not equal equal
# 5 5e    e    5    d    5 not equal equal
```

Comment: You can also use just `df$let <- df$let1 == df$let2` instead of the `ifelse(df$let1 == df$let2, "equal", "not equal")`

Comment: I know that. I wrote exactly like you initially. Finally, I changed my code to make it more explicitly.

Comment: This is pretty cool.  I like the explicit coding style as well, I actually modified it to `df$let <- ifelse(df$let1 == df$let2, "equal", paste(df$let1, df$let2, sep = " =/= ")` so now when the data does not match, I can quickly audit it to see if it's something like `international =/= intl` or something like that.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like `which`? Quick reproducible example:

```
> m1 <- m2 <- matrix(1:9, 3)
> diag(m1) <- 0
> which(m1 != m2, arr.ind = TRUE)
     row col
[1,]   1   1
[2,]   2   2
[3,]   3   3
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
df_diff <- list()

 for (i in 1:ncol(df1)) 
{
 df_diff[[i]] <- df1$id[df2[i] != df1[i]]
 names(df_diff)[i] <- names(df1)[i]
}
```

This should produce (hopefully :)) a list of character vectors (one for each variable). Each vector contains the IDs of df1 where the records of the two df don't match.